# How to use Google app script automatically creating a "page break" in exporting a Google sheet as pdf

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a table in Google sheet. 5 Columns, ~200 rows
Some of the rows are blank cells to indicate the "continuous rows" belongs to the same group. (i.e. same date belongs to the same group, there are about 10 groups)

I am using the url with parameter approach (see the link) to export that table into a pdf

I want to have the result like this.
Group 1 in page 1

If there is enough space to squeeze all data of Group 2 in page 1,then just place the Group 2 in page 1, otherwise, manually page break and make the group 2 on page 2

Repeat the above for group 3,4,5... data.

My problem is:
How to detect the Group 2 data doesn't fit into page 1?

I can provide some sample data later if I need further explanation on my problem

Comment: There is no link. Would you please edit the question to include sample data as well as an example of a successful outcome.